# roswtf warnings: unexpectedly connected

Tags: ros, rviz, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
when I run roswtf I get the following warning. Why does it think the nodes are unexpectedly connected?

```
Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /rviz_1299863506781450302->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /openni_node1->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_base1_link2->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /openni_node2->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_base_link1->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_base_link->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_base2_link3->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_base1_link3->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_base2_link2->/rosout (/rosout)
```

Best,

CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9385/roswtf-warnings:-unexpectedly-connected./) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These messages are normal (but annoying).

As it says: "warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault".

I would like to know how to eliminate them, too.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-07-18**:
Good to know but still a bit unsatisfying. If the condition is normal then why is there a warning at all? Under what conditions can it be ignored?

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-11**:
hmmm...good to know